# How to add c++ experimental library to mac compiler?

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to add experimental library to mac os x.
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental

how can i add this ?

Comment: There is no "Mac compiler". There's Xcode (clang LLVM) and `gcc`, among others if you're feeling adventurous. Do try and be specific about which you're using when asking questions of this nature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no "experimental" library.

All of the C++ technical specifications that add to the standard library put their definitions into the `std::experimental` namespace. So `std::experimental::future` comes from the Concurrency TS. That TS effectively defines a few new functions in `std::future`, but it does so essentially by creating a new type in a new namespace with the old functions plus a few new ones. Should the TS be incorporated into the standard proper, those features will be added directly to `std::future`.

These technical specifications are effectively *optional* features that your standard library implementation may or may not support. If it does not support them, you may find libraries that provide the TS's functionality. For example, the FileSystem TS was based on Boost.Filesystem.

But there is no one thing you can download which will ensure that you will have all of the stuff in `std::experimental`.